# How to fix a issue with calculating a student's level grade (e.g.11th grade)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use dates to identify the current grade level of a student (e.g. 11th Grade), with a cutoff date in mind.

In this instance, my cutoff date is supposed to be October 1st. Ideally, someone who's born September 30, 2000 is supposed to be "College and beyond", but for someone who's born on October 1, 2000, they're still in 12th grade.

However, my formula seems to have a problem. Unusually, it shows dates between October 1, 2000 and December 31, 2000 as if they are in college...when they're not. For example, the date December 26, 2000 should be saying "12", not "College and beyond".

I tried evaluating the formulas to try to solve the issue, but as it turns out, the formulas I entered turned true and identified it as being correct, when they're not.

This is what the table looks like:

[image]

The Grade column is what it should look like, the Test column is what it's it right now.

And the formula I used to state these level grades is this.

```
=IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2)),YEAR(B2)+18<YEAR(TODAY())),"College and beyond",IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),12,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),11,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+2,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),10,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+3,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),9,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+4,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),8,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+5,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),7,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+6,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),6,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+7,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),5,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+8,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),4,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+9,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),3,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+10,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),2,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+11,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),1,IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+12,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),"Kindergarden",IF(AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+13,MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2))),"Pre-K","Not in school")))))))))))))))
```

Comment: As you get "College and beyond" as answer means that the first part of the formula: `AND(DATE(YEAR(B2)+18,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))<DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH($H$2),DAY($H$2)),YEAR(B2)+18<YEAR(TODAY()))` evaluates to true. So start with checking that expression.

Comment: If those are real names and DOBs for students, you should probably remove that image and replace it with a redacted version. FERPA, privacy, security, etc.

Comment: @YDavis Those are names and DOBs I made up. They aren't really real, just some John Does.

Comment: The problem stems from YEAR(TODAY()). The output of this formula will change on January 1st, since YEAR(TODAY()) will change. Presumably you want this to change at the beginning of a school year (Sep 1st?), so you should be adjusting for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table showing age and grade relationships (I put the table in columns H and I, though it could be moved to a different sheet if preferred), and then your formula becomes very simple.  In cell D2 and down:

```
=VLOOKUP(DATEDIF(B2,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),9,30),"y"),$H$2:$I$17,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your assistance!